# class.save error ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, console, save

I'm learning ruby on rails by following Patrick Lenz's book from Sitepoint. I know it's a bit outdated, so I'm adapting as I go along.

I've gotten to a place where I'm in my rails console, ready to start creating/saving to my database, and when I create a class, then type story.save, I get this error:

```
1.9.3p194 :007 > story.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "stories" ("link", "name") VALUES (?, ?)  [["link", nil], ["name", nil]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "stories" ("link", "name") VALUES (?, ?)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "stories" ("link", "name") VALUES (?, ?)
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:263:in `to_a'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:263:in `block in exec_query'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:242:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:63:in `exec_insert'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:90:in `insert'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:66:in `insert'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:363:in `create'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create'
... 14 levels...
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/ideogram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3p194 :008 >
```

I have no idea what this means. Any ideas? Help is much appreciated. :)

I'm running on a Macbook Pro OSX Lion 10.7.3, Ruby 1.9.3-194, Rails 3.2.3. Have installed homebrew, rvm, and then several packages including readlines, sqlite3, and git.

THANK YOU!

Addendum: here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0) do

  create_table "stories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "link"
  end

  add_index "stories", ["id"], :name => "sqlite_autoindex_stories_1", :unique => true

end
```

This is the sqlite command I used to create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `stories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: looks like you are trying to save nil values into fields that don't allow nil/null values. That is what the constraint failed is referring to.

Comment: what contains `story.inspect` before `save`?

Comment: `"#<Story id: nil, name: nil, link: nil>"` is what shows up...

Comment: is the issue in my database itself?? it's letting me create the class fine. should I add values that are not nil?

Comment: Did you set up your `stories` table using the SQL Patrick Lenz provides in his tutorial?

Comment: Yes, he used sqlite3, and in the code archive the file with the table creation text is available for copy/paste

Comment: What did you do to create the story object in the first place (e.g. `story = Story.new(:name => 'something', :link => 'something else')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all very much for helping me out.

Between your comments, I figured out the issue.  The issue was in my database -- it wasn't created correctly so once I had deleted the original file and then recompiled the file again (making sure all of my commas were in the correct place) then it finally worked!

I appreciate all your help, so thank you again. I learned quite a bit from your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nil values are the problem -- you can change that in the migration if you need to allow nil.

Lots of ways to verify the details from console

```
> story.valid?
> story.errors (after a save)
```

etc etc

The migration (or your db/schema.rb) would be helpful as well

Comment: It gives me for `story.valid?` `true`, and I will post my schema above

Answer (score 1):

stories table are not in your migration. Maybe you created it by hand (sql) with not null contraints. Since Rails have no clue about those constrains, it trows an error from your DB

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your schema, you don't have a `stories` table. <strike>The Patrick Lenz tutorial uses MySQL as a database but you are using SQLite3.</strike> (I was looking at an old article of his. It appears he updated the article in 2011) Since you have a schema file, I'm guessing that you are using migration files to generate your database tables. If so, your `link` and `name` fields would default to `:null => true` and hence would have no qualms about holding a `nil` value.

Is it possible that you forgot to `rake db:migrate` after creating the migration file for your `stories` table?

Comment: That is quite possible, as that wasn't a step in the book. I'm going to double check my tables and make sure they're in the schema, and then `rake db:migrate` and see what happens.  Back in a few!

Comment: All right, here is my schema with the story table. `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0) do

  create_table "stories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "link"
  end

  add_index "stories", ["id"], :name => "sqlite_autoindex_stories_1", :unique => true

end`  ran `rake db:migrate` and still the same error.

Comment: Did you close out of the console and restart your server? A migration won't take effect until then.

Comment: Am I creating my sqlite table incorrectly? I pasted the command I used to create the table in the original post above.

Comment: Doesn't look like you are doing it wrong. Your two fields `name` and `link` are defaulted to `NULL` and in Rails, my understanding is that `NULL` maps to `nil`.

Comment: All right, thanks so much, I'm going to try to add actual values to the objects instead of just leaving them null. then see what happens.